# MVC ScriptManager XHTML Transitional Doctype validation error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, doctype, scriptmanager

The server side team are using the following MVC ScriptManager in my current project
:

http://mvcscriptmanager.codeplex.com/

It is causing a small validation error whereby the generated, concatenated script does not output the type="text/JavaScript" attribute.

It's no big deal but i was wondering how i can make this ScriptManager output valid XHTML in this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the server side developers fixed this issue by updating the ScriptManager itself.